# SQL Server Assistance in creating a Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am creating a database for a project for class and we were shown how to create a foreign key relationship (using SQL Server 2012) by clicking the relationship button and adding the new relationship to the table but for some reason I cannot change the foreign key table (like we did in class).

I tried to include a screen shot but I cannot do so yet. Anyway I can show exactly what I mean?????

MY tables begin with Category, Costume, Customer, Payment, and Rental all of which are the ID's (int) for each table. (Category being the first and main)

Comment: I don't see a screenshot.  Can you include the sql code (ddl) for the tables you are trying to create?

Comment: Are you in the designer?

Comment: i thought it added the screen shot but it said i cant because i dont have enough reputation. I go through the Object explorer and create the new tables by Right clicking tables (under appropriate database) and clicking New table. Then adding the different fields for each table. I have the Primary Key set to the ID for each table and with that selected I click the Relationship button. Does this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in the GUI, but you can create a foreign key pretty simply through DDL:

```
alter table dbo.ChildTable add
   constraint [FK_Child_Parent] foreign key (col1, col2)
      references dbo.ParentTable (col1, col2)
```

Comment: okay so if the parent table is category then the child table would be the costume. so would it show...
alter table dbo.CostumeTable add
   constraint [FK_Costume_Category] foreign key (col1, col2)
      references dbo.CategoryTable (col1, col2)